# Centos 5 X86 64 Daemon for shell script

Tags: centos, daemon

I have made a shell script to run a server for a game I like. I need the server to run when I close putty. Right now putty is the console, but I need it to not close when I close the program down.

startServer.sh:
    `~/server_1/srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_bigcity`
I need it to run everything in there daemonized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
nohup $HOME/server_1/srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_bigcity & > logfile 2>&1
```

logfile is if you want to keep track of what is coming to the screen. if you don't care, replace it with /dev/null

`man nohup` for further info

Comment: Got it working thanks, I will forever be greatful